# Show "Acceptable client certificate CA names" section in LibreSSL

Tags: openssl

I would like to see the trust store of a server configured for mTLS using `openssl` on macOS. I can do this on Linux because `openssl` provides the "Acceptable client certificate CA names" section in the output

```
# Linux
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021

$ echo | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com -showcerts
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
.
.
.
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
.
. # The list of CAs I'm interested in
.
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
```

However, running the same command on macOS I don't see the section, presumably because it's using LibreSSL

```
# macOS
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 3.3.6

$ echo | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -servername example.com -showcerts
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
.
.
.
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
```

Is there anyway to show the "Acceptable client certificate CA names" section (or it's equivalent) in LibreSSL?

Comment: It clearly says "No client certificate CA names sent", so there is no such list it receives. If there is no such list coming from the server, it cannot show it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So the server sends the list in response to a request from OpenSSL 1.1. Why would it not for the same request coming from LibreSSL 3.3? Is there some extra option I need to pass for the LibreSSL command?

Comment: *"So the server sends the list in response to a request from OpenSSL 1.1"* - No. The server sends the list if it a) requires client certificates and b) is configured to send the list. It has nothing to do with a "request" from the client. *"Why would it not for the same request coming from LibreSSL 3.3?"* - unfortunately nothing is known about the server and its configuration. There is no way to reproduce what you are seeing without this or without being able to probe the server.